# Can you see failed outbound messages in dev environment?

Tags: sandbox, workflowoutboundmessage

I'm trying to test the instance where a Salesforce outbound message fails to be acknowledge by the endpoint but I'm unable to see the outbound messages appear in the Outbound Message Status queue where they should get retried.  I know they are not being received by the endpoint since I've tried changing the endpoint URL in Salesforce to something invalid.  When the URL is correct, the messages are received.  Does the outbound message delivery status/failed message retry functionality exist in the sandbox environment or is this only available in production environments?